# Usage of the word "introspect"

Tags: verbs, word-usage

I am trying to write a sentence to mean that something made me think deeply about myself and I would really like to use the word *introspect*. I came up with:

> During several instances of reading that book, I felt the need to stop
>   and introspect...

Is there a better way to say what I am trying to say? Can anyone give me examples of using this word as a verb without changing it to its noun form, *introspection*?

Comment: You'd probably be better served using "*reflect*".

Comment: [*Oxford*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/introspect) has numerous sentence examples, but they all sound stuffy or old-fashioned. I'd go with @DanBron's suggestion.

Comment: Reminds me of the old Burke quote: "*“Reading without reflecting is like eating without digesting.*".

Comment: Dan Bron - reflect would do the job too... 
I was wondering if introspect could ever be used in a sentence in the verb form and sound correct.

Comment: Short answer is "yes", but because it's uncommon, it might draw attention to itself (as a a word), rather than transparently conveying the idea you're aiming for. But the effect won't be large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the verb "introspect" is perfectly *acceptable*, it's not *advisable*.  When you use that word, listeners/readers stop listening to *what you say*, and instead think about *how you're saying it.*  If nobody is listening to what you say, why bother saying it?

Poets use words that way, writing things that people walk around, inspecting it from all angles, admiring it - but it doesn't effectively communicate ideas, which is why it doesn't get used in advertising or in campaign speeches.  Rap "music" is poetry - and it's hated by most people.  The lyrics in other music gets washed down with pretty tunes, leaving a few limericks about girls from Nantucket as the only poems most people enjoy.

In other words, it's couth to keep your language ept!

Answer (score 0):

I have frankly never heard the word used as a verb like that.  I would write it like this:

> Several times while reading it, the book caused me to become introspective.